# pygame event.get Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate

Tags: python, pygame, fatal-error

I have a python program with a Tkinter and Pygame window and is doing a few things with win32gui which might be the cause to the error

```
Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate

Current thread 0x00004344 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\stemb\Documents\programing\python\programs\img editor\FIND_PARTS.py", line 489 in handleEvents
  File "C:\Users\stemb\Documents\programing\python\programs\img editor\FIND_PARTS.py", line 456 in main
  File "C:\Users\stemb\Documents\programing\python\programs\img editor\FIND_PARTS.py", line 554 in main
  File "C:/Users/stemb/Documents/programing/python/programs/img editor/__init__.py", line 79 in main
  File "C:/Users/stemb/Documents/programing/python/programs/img editor/__init__.py", line 86 in <module>
```

when I run `for event in pygame.event.get():`

I am running windows 10 and using PyCharm

Edit:

After a bit more testing, i have found out that it is caused by the `<Configure>` bind the tkinter window so I could keep it next to the pygame window.

Comment: Why use pygame and tkinter together in the first place?

Comment: @unlut I have them in 2 separate windows because i need different things like a list box which is easy to do in tkinter and a image with things drawn on it which is easier to use with pygame

Comment: Maybe you could run these as separate processes?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when trying to make Pygame and tkinter play nicely, getting `Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate` when calling `pygame.event.get()` after trying to open a tkinter file dialog.

I solved it by passing `pump=False` to `pygame.event.get()` and manually calling `pygame.event.pump()` at the end of the event loop, like so:

```
for event in pygame.event.get(pump=False):

    # Process events here

    pygame.event.pump()
```

My guess is that Pygame and tkinter can fight over internal events, and this handles when tkinter is doing something that blocks the main loop (like opening a file dialog).